# Can a character with Extra Attack replace multiple attacks with Grapple special attacks, as part of the same Attack action?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple

> When you want to grab a creature or wrestle with it, you can use the Attack action to make a special melee attack, a grapple. If you're able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, **this attack replaces one of them**.

Does this mean a character with the Extra Attack feature can replace both attacks granted by their Attack action with grapples, or can only replace one of them?

Comment: related: [Shoving multiple times with multiple attacks](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114477)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The quoted section refers to the fact that one grapple attempt uses up only one attack and not a whole Attack Action.

Thus multiple attempts to grapple can be made in a turn if you have Extra Attacks.

This is also [supported by Jeremy Crawford,](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/700143392257249281) who says:

> If you take the Attack action and have multiple attacks, you can replace any of them with a grapple/shove.

(Thanks to Doval, who found this tweet.)

Comment: @Sdjz Unfortunately this is another case where the lack of explicit forbiddance is the only thing one can point to. If they wanted to say that you can only attempt grappling once per action, they would have worded that sentence differently. I have not found any clarification is sage advice either.

Comment: Crawford's been asked about this before. ["If you take the Attack action and have multiple attacks, you can replace any of them with a grapple/shove."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/700143392257249281)