# Can a character with Extra Attack replace multiple attacks with Shoves as part of the same Attack action?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat-maneuver

In the PHB, page 195, it is stated in the rules of shoving that:

> If you're able to make multiple attacks with the attack action, this
>   attack replace one of them.

Because of this, combined with the ability to break up your movement on your turn, could someone shove a creature with their first attack, move up, then shove again?

Comment: related: [Can a character with Extra Attack replace multiple attacks with Grapple special attacks, as part of the same Attack action?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97646)

Comment: Welcome to the RPG Stack Exchange! You may want to take our [tour] for a brief introduction to who we are and the way the site works. Thank you for your very good question! I've cleaned the formatting up a bit for you, but you can go back and change that at any time by using the [edit] button below your question.

Answer (score 17):

## Yes

As you said, the rules for shoving say:

> If you're able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack **replaces one of them**.

Since the shove only replaces one of the attacks, you then have enough actions left from the other attacks to shove again. Of course, this assumes that you have enough movement to move 5 feet forward to get into range to shove the creature again.

**If you have attack(s) and movement available, then you can absolutely shove multiple times.**

This argument is essentially the same one that you can read with regards to grappling in this [Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97646/can-a-character-with-extra-attack-replace-multiple-attacks-with-grapple-special).

## Unofficial ruling

[Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/700143392257249281), lead rules designer for D&D, agrees with this ruling (even including the very similar case of Grappling):

> If you take the Attack action and have multiple attacks, you can
> replace **any of them** with a grapple/shove.

Comment: Although I totally agree with your point and the ruling, this once again points out Crawford's maddening habit of almost but not quite answering the question by way of vague wording. "Replace any of them" could as easily mean "replace any *one* of them"  as "replace any *or all* of them".

Comment: @keithcurtis and probably should mean that. Those are all attacks.