# Do I have to attack to use Extra Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, actions, fighter, action-economy

Do I have to attack to use Extra Attack? Or can I do something different with my action on my turn and use this feature to attack?
So for example, say I use Dash, Disengage, or Cast a Spell; can I still attack with Extra Attack?

The reason to ask all this is that I want to know if I can cast the [*blade ward*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/blade-ward) cantrip (PHB, p. 218) from [Magic Initiate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/magic-initiate) (PHB, p. 168) every round and still have the ability to attack.

Comment: Related: [How does a Fighter's Extra Attack feature work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165652/33569)

Comment: I read this thread and for some mystical reason i didn't see second paragraph from the first answer. Simply magic. I think this thread can be closed or deleted.

Comment: While that answer does address your question, the questions aren't quite asking the same thing, so I wouldn't close your question as a duplicate of that one... I think it's fine to leave your question up as a signpost in case any others wonder the same thing in the future - no need to close or delete it.

Answer (score 7):

### Yes, you need to attack to take advantage of Extra Attack

The fighter's [Extra Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#ExtraAttack-196) feature says:

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

As stated, you need to take the Attack action, using up your one available action for that turn, but now you can attack twice within that action.

You cannot take any other action (Disengage, Cast a Spell, etc.) and then swing a weapon as well as part of the same action, unless specific rules explicitly state otherwise.

Comment: I know, I know but I wanted to keep it clean without introducing too many caveats.